# jQuery login issue

Tags: jquery

I have a link with two classes:

```
<a href="#" class="loginable postStory">Share Your Quirks</a>
```

loginable checks if user is logged in and, if not, presents a "modal" login popup:

```
$(".loginable").live("click",function(e) {                        
    $.getJSON("/cfcs/global.cfc?method=userAuthenticated&returnformat=json", {}, function(res,code) {
        if(res == 0){
            doSiteLogin();
        }
    });
})
```

postStory loads a form for adding a story:

```
$(".postStory").live("click", function(e) {
    $(function() {
        $("#divCentre").load(siteRoot + "add_story.cfm?mode=create");
    })
});
```

The idea is that once the link is clicked, we don't want to show the add_story page unless the user is logged in, i.e. we need to user to stay on the current page UNTIL they've successfully logged in. But currently, it displays the add_story page AND the login popup.

To see what I mean, go to www.quirkup.com and click the "Share your quirks" link at the top of the "True Confessions" section.

The problem is that the user can close the modal window without logging in and can start filling in the form. I realise I can probably hide the form until the login is completed, but I'm wondering if there's a better way.

### Edit

THe doSiteLogin() function looks like this

```
function doSiteLogin() {
        ColdFusion.Window.create('loginwindow','Login','/inc_site_login_form.cfm',{x:400,y:300,height:200,width:300,center:true,modal:true});
    }

    function handleSiteLogin() {
        ColdFusion.Ajax.submitForm('siteloginform','/processLogin.cfm',handleSiteLoginResponse);
    }

    function handleSiteLoginResponse(s) { 
        var userid = s.split("^")[0] || 0;
        var firstname = s.split("^")[1] || 0;
        var lastname = s.split("^")[2] || 0;
        var usertype = s.split("^")[3] || 0;
        var confirmed = s.split("^")[4] || 0;
        var enabled = s.split("^")[5] || 0;
        var authenticated = s.split("^")[6] || 0;

        if(authenticated == 1){
            ColdFusion.Window.hide('loginwindow');
            alert('Successfully logged in.\nRefreshing page...');
            window.location.reload();
        }else{
            if(confirmed != 1){
                alert('Your account has not been activated. Please ensure you have clicked the confirmation link in your email.');
                return false;
            }else if(!enabled || enabled.toLowerCase() == 'no'){
                alert('Your account is not activated. Please contact Quirkup.');
                return false;
            }else{
                alert('Your login failed. Please try again.\nIf the problem persists, or you have forgotten your login details, please email info@asia-buy.com.');
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why you have 2 classes and 2 events for this... it should be:

```
$(".loginable").live("click",function(e) {                        
    $.getJSON("/cfcs/global.cfc?method=userAuthenticated&returnformat=json", {}, function(res,code) {
        if(res == 0){
            doSiteLogin();
        } else {
            $("#divCentre").load(siteRoot + "add_story.cfm?mode=create");
        }
    });
})
```

A simple else statement should fix that part. Now when a user isnt logged and logs in you can do this...

```
function handleSiteLoginResponse(s) { 
    var userid = s.split("^")[0] || 0;
    var firstname = s.split("^")[1] || 0;
    var lastname = s.split("^")[2] || 0;
    var usertype = s.split("^")[3] || 0;
    var confirmed = s.split("^")[4] || 0;
    var enabled = s.split("^")[5] || 0;
    var authenticated = s.split("^")[6] || 0;

    if(authenticated == 1){
        ColdFusion.Window.hide('loginwindow');
        $("#divCentre").load(siteRoot + "add_story.cfm?mode=create");
    }else{
        if(confirmed != 1){
            alert('Your account has not been activated. Please ensure you have clicked the confirmation link in your email.');
            return false;
        }else if(!enabled || enabled.toLowerCase() == 'NO'){
            alert('Your account is not activated. Please contact Quirkup.');
            return false;
        }else{
            alert('Your login failed. Please try again.\nIf the problem persists, or you have forgotten your login details, please email info@asia-buy.com.');
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

There's no reason to reload the page. Also, never use an "Alert()" method to tell the user something. It stops the entire page from doing anything. It quite literally freezes javascript.

Comment: Because loginable is a generic function for ANY link that requires a login first.

Comment: Then just show them a user login form via a redirect. It's strange (and hard from a programming standpoint) to handle user authentication with javascript.

Comment: The page reloads to do a recheck on user session var to display features and links for those logged in. I WANT the processing to stop after the alerts. I've even added return falses to ensure that happens. Forget about how I've programmed it. I just need a solution for not displaying the form until the log in is complete and I'll be happy.